# Firestore Snapshot listeners are not in my code but shows in Subscription Metrics

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, cloud

I'm building a Nuxt 3 app with Firestore. I only use `getDocs` to read data, and no `onSnapshot` function. But the Subscription Metrics in my Firebase app shows that I have up to 4 snapshot listeners and 15 active connections at peak. I'm also testing my app in 1 browser tab only. Am I missing something?